# How do I do decrements in C language?

Tags: c

If an example , I set a value of :

```
a = 50
```

How do I do a decrement whereby a always decreases by 2 ? An example :

```
48
46
44
42
40
```

Whereby the return results , I can use as a variable. Example in the case below , this method is to get temperature at random. But I would like it to decrease so that I can call this get temperature method even below for it to loop.

```
/* Retrieves current temperature. */
static int32_t get_temperature_sample(void)
{
    /* For the sake of example, random data is used */
    return rand() % 10 + 25;
}

/* Periodically called by Kaa SDK. */
static void example_callback(void *context)
{
    time_t current_time = time(NULL);

    /* Respect sample period */
    if (difftime(current_time, last_sample_time) >= sample_period) {
        int32_t temperature = get_temperature_sample();

        printf("Sampled temperature: %i\n", temperature);
        last_sample_time = current_time;

        kaa_user_log_record_t *log_record = kaa_logging_data_collection_create();
        log_record->temperature = temperature;

        kaa_logging_add_record(kaa_client_get_context(context)->log_collector, log_record, NULL);
    }
}
```

Like if the above codes , if I were to say that for my temperature. I wouldnt want it to be random as you can see it uses random. I want to set a value for my temperature and decrease like a constant until it reaches 0 in my print function shown below.

```
printf("Sampled temperature: %i\n", temperature);
        last_sample_time = current_time;
```

Comment: How about `a-=2;`

Comment: C don't have concept of method.

Comment: Adding onto what @dbush said, you could pass in a parameter into the get_sample_temperature(int * prev) function that is the previous temp. Then just do prev-=2, return prev.

Comment: dont get it... is there an example (: @TMartin

Comment: C does not support _methods_. And those are functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
static void get_temperature_sample(int *previous_temp)
{
    *previous_temp -= 2; // This decrements the value and 
                         // don't need a return value, because
                         // you are passing a pointer to
                         // the variable and hence modifying
                         // it's value directly
}
```

And when you call the function

```
int32_t temperature = 50;      // Initial temperature
get_temperature_sample(&temperature);
```

You'll need to add a while somewhere in there depending on how you're tracking the temperature. But this will decrement the temp value whenever you call the function.

Answer (score 0):

To decrement `a`, try using

```
 a -=2;
```

it will help you..

Comment: Lets say if i were to try a -=2 , it doesnt show loop. it just stops at 48